# How to delete columns with at least 20% missing values

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Is there an efficient way to delete columns that have at least 20% missing values?

Suppose my dataframe is like:

```
   A      B      C      D
0  sg     hh     1      7
1  gf                   9
2  hh                   10
3  dd                   8
4                       6 
5  y                    8`
```

After removing the columns, the dataframe becomes like this:

```
   A       D
0  sg      7
1  gf      9
2  hh      10
3  dd      8
4          6 
5  y       8`
```

Comment: you can use df.isnull(), which will return a boolean df/series of the same size. sum the rows for each column of the result and divide by the total rows? then delete columns appropriately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `boolean indexing` on the `columns` where the count of `notnull` values is larger then `80%`:

```
df.loc[:, pd.notnull(df).sum()>len(df)*.8]
```

This is useful for many cases, e.g., dropping the columns where the number of values larger than `1` would be:

```
df.loc[:, (df > 1).sum() > len(df) *. 8]
```

Alternatively, for the `.dropna()` case, you can also specify the `thresh` keyword of `.dropna()` as illustrated by @EdChum:

```
df.dropna(thresh=0.8*len(df), axis=1)
```

The latter will be slightly faster:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
for col in df:
    df.loc[np.random.choice(list(range(100)), np.random.randint(10, 30)), col] = np.nan

%timeit df.loc[:, pd.notnull(df).sum()>len(df)*.8]
1000 loops, best of 3: 716 µs per loop

%timeit df.dropna(thresh=0.8*len(df), axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 537 µs per loop
```

Comment: which one will be more efficient in your above two methods

Comment: `.dropna()` will be a bit faster.

Answer (score 4):

You can call [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) and pass a `thresh` value to drop the columns that don't meet your threshold criteria:

```
In [10]:    
frac = len(df) * 0.8
df.dropna(thresh=frac, axis=1)

Out[10]:
     A   D
0   sg   7
1   gf   9
2   hh  10
3   dd   8
4  NaN   6
5    y   8
```